# How to use Jinja2 filters on reserved key names?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a dictionary (let's call it `source`) coming from an Ansible inventory with an optional `values` property.

I'm trying to use the value of that property or a default, but cannot use `{{ source.values() | default({}) }}` because `values` points to Python's standard `dict.values()` method.

I know I can simply do `{{ source.get('values', {}) }}` but I think this may not cover some edge cases that Jinja would catch (for example, null values).

Is there a way in Jinja to have the same behaviour as object.key notation minus the errors on reserved keys?